# Group multiple rows by multiple fields and replace one field with it total sum Django

Tags: django, django-models, aggregate, grouping

Let's assume that I have such model in Django represented with below table and Model class (in database it exist as a view):

```
id  Name     Year  Month  Project Name     City    Total
1   Joe Doe  2020  7     Project_A        SomeCity  10
1   Joe Doe  2020  7     Project_A        SomeCity  30
1   Joe Doe  2020  7     Project_A        SomeCity  30
1   Joe Doe  2020  8     Project_A        SomeCity  10
1   Joe Doe  2020  8     Project_A        SomeCity  30
1   Joe Doe  2020  8     Project_A        SomeCity  30
```

models.py:

```
class Model_View(models.Model):
  employee_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
  name = models.TextField()
  year = models.IntegerField()
  month = models.IntegerField()
  project_name = models.TextField()
  city = models.TextField()
  total = models.IntegerField()
```

The result which I'm expecting is:

```
id   Name     Year  Month  Project Name   City      Total
1   Joe Doe 2020    7    Project_A      SomeCity    70
1   Joe Doe 2020    8    Project_A      SomeCity    70
```

I've tried to achieve this using:

```
Model.objects.values().order_by('Project Name', 'Month').annotate(Total=Sum('Total'))
```

Unfortunately result of this operation is slightly different from expected one:

```
id   Name     Year  Month  Project Name   City      Total
1   Joe Doe 2020    7    Project_A      SomeCity    60
1   Joe Doe 2020    7    Project_A      SomeCity    10
1   Joe Doe 2020    8    Project_A      SomeCity    60
1   Joe Doe 2020    8    Project_A      SomeCity    10
```

At first look I thought that those records are just different and that's why it's not grouped together, but after looking thoroughly I see group_by should work on those.

So, what could be problem here?

EDIT:
I think it could be important data is retrieved from a view, not from real model.

Comment: `Model.objects.values().order_by('Project Name', 'Month').annotate(percentage=Sum('Total'))`

Comment: That would be case, but I just forget to change name of column in code.

Comment: Please add **models.py** in for more clarifications.